# Issue when trying to switch with _driver.Context = "WEBVIEW_chrome" statement, using appium/selenium in c#

Tags: appium

Open the app and do some actions using appiumdriver.

Reinstating the driver to use WebView_Chrome with :

string chromedriverPath = "C:\...\bin\Debug\net6.0\chromedriver.exe";
var androidOptions = new AppiumOptions();
androidOptions.AddAdditionalCapability("platformName",TestConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PlatformName"].Value);
androidOptions.AddAdditionalCapability("platformVersion",TestConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PlatformVersion"].Value);
androidOptions.AddAdditionalCapability("deviceName",TestConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DeviceName"].Value);
androidOptions.AddAdditionalCapability("udId",TestConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Udid"].Value);
androidOptions.AddAdditionalCapability("chromedriver_autodownload", true);
androidOptions.AddAdditionalCapability("appPackage", "com.android.chrome");
androidOptions.AddAdditionalCapability("appActivity", "com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main");
androidOptions.AddAdditionalCapability("chromedriverEnableAsync", true);
androidOptions.AddAdditionalCapability("chromedriverChromeMapping", "119.0.6045");
androidOptions.AddAdditionalCapability("chromedriverExecutable", chromedriverPath);

AndroidDriver _driver = new AndroidDriver(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), androidOptions);

```
        // Wait for the WebView context to be available
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(_driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(40));
        wait.Until(driver => _driver.Contexts.Contains("WEBVIEW_chrome"));

        // Print available contexts
        var contexts = _driver.Contexts;
        foreach (var context in contexts)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Available context: " + context);
        }
        _driver.Context = "WEBVIEW_chrome";
        // Wait for the context switch, if needed (you might need to adjust the wait time)
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        string currentContext = _driver.Context;
        Console.WriteLine($"Current Context: {currentContext}");

        // Navigate to bbc.co.uk
        _driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.bbc.co.uk");
```

-> error: The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub/session/..../context timed out after 60 seconds. (90.8s)